# Should you standardize when using a Log link?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, standardization, link-function

If I use a model with a log link function should I still standardize independent variables (since they differ in the scales range) or the log transformation is enough?

Comment: Standardizing and any other linear transformation, for use in linear models, does not change the estimated effects - only the units are changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a simple example, where you are trying to model salary (Y) as a function of years of experience (X) for employees of a large company.

After exploring the data on a random sample of n = 50 employees of the company, you feel comfortable fitting a Gamma regression model to the (X,Y) data collected for the sample.

Your first model assumes that the log-transformed expected salary is a function of years of experience:

$log(E(Y|X)) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 * X$

Because X was not standardized in this model, you can interpret $\beta_1$ as follows:

Having 1 more year of experience is associated with an multiplicative increase in the expected (or average) salary given by $exp(\beta_1)$.

Your second model assumes that the log-transformed expected salary is a function of the standadized years of experience:

$log(E(Y|X)) = \beta_{0s} + \beta_{1s}*X_s$

Because X was standardized in this model, you can interpret $\beta_{1s}$ as follows:

Having one SD more years of experience is associated with a multiplicative increase in the expected (or average) salary given by $exp(\beta_1)$. Here, SD refers to the observed standard deviation of the variable 'years of experience' in the sample of employees. For example, if SD = 5 years and the estimated value of $\beta_{1s}$ is equal to 0.5, then you can say that having 5 more years of experience is associated with an increase in the expected (or average) salary of $(exp(0.5) - 1)*100%$ (roughly a 65% increase).

As you can see, standardizing the X affects the magnitude of increase in the values of X that you will relate to a multiplicative change in the expected (or average) value of Y.  The link itself affects what transformation of the expected value of Y given X you are modelling - in this example, you are modelling the log-transformed expected value of Y given X.